# TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typeerror, addeventlistener

I got this Error message: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined" and I don't know why. I think it has to do with the fact that variable "el" loads the first time with the value of zero but I am not sure and I dont know how to solve that issue.

**EDIT:**
I updated the code with the help of the answers. Now I got a new error message "TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined" https://jsfiddle.net/Van_Gram/4vofz6jh/7/

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { addToCart } from './actions/cartActions'
import StackGrid from "react-stack-grid"
import Tilt from 'react-tilt'


// normally these would be `import` statements bundled by webpack
const { ReactDOM } = window;

 class Home extends Component{

   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.unlockStartHandler = this.unlockStartHandler.bind(this);
     this.unlockEndHandler = this.unlockEndHandler.bind(this);
     this.animateHandler = this.animateHandler.bind(this);
     this.successHandler = this.successHandler.bind(this);
     this.maxValue = 150;
     this.speed = 12;
     this.currValue = 0;
     this.rafID = null;
   }

   /*componentDidMount() {
     // bind events
    this.inputRange.addEventListener('mousedown', this.unlockStartHandler, false);
    this.inputRange.addEventListener('mousestart', this.unlockStartHandler, false);
    this.inputRange.addEventListener('mouseup', this.unlockEndHandler, false);
    this.inputRange.addEventListener('touchend', this.unlockEndHandler, false);
   }*/

   // listen for unlock
   unlockStartHandler(e) {
     // clear raf if trying again
     window.cancelAnimationFrame(this.rafID);
     // set to desired value
     this.currValue = +e.target.value;
   }

   unlockEndHandler(e) {
       // store current value
       this.currValue = +e.target.value;
       // determine if we have reached success or not
       if(this.currValue >= this.maxValue) {
           this.successHandler();
           this.sendData();
       }
       else {
           this.rafID = window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animateHandler);
       }
     }

     // handle range animation
   animateHandler() {
     // update input range
     this.inputRange.value = this.currValue;
     // determine if we need to continue
     if(this.currValue > -1) {
       window.requestAnimationFrame(this.animateHandler);
     }
     // decrement value
     this.currValue = this.currValue - this.speed;
   }

   // handle successful unlock
   successHandler = (prevState) => {
     // alert('unlocked');
     // reset input range
     this.inputRange.value = 0;
   };

   sendData = () => {
     this.props.parentCallback(null);
   }

   callbackFunction = (childData) => {
     /*this.setState((prevState) => ({
       counter: prevState.counter + 1,
     }));*/
   }

    handleClick = (id)=>{
        this.props.addToCart(id);
    }



    render(){
        let itemList = this.props.items.map(item=>{
            return(
              <Tilt className="Tilt" options={{ max : 10 }, { perspective : 3000 }, {scale : 0.97}} >
                <div className="card" key={item.id}>
                  <div className="card-image">
                    <img src={item.img} alt={item.title}/>
                  </div>

                  <div className="card-content">
                    <h2 className="card-title">{item.title}</h2>
                    <p>{item.desc}</p>
                    <div className="slider">
                      <h3>Swipe um zu bestellen</h3>
                      <input
                        type="range"
                        defaultValue={0}
                        min={0}
                        max={150}
                        className="pullee"
                        /*ref={(el) => { this.inputRange = el; }}*/
                      />
                    </div>
                    <span to="/" className="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light red" onClick={()=>{this.handleClick(item.id)}}><i className="material-icons">add</i></span>
                  </div>
                 </div>
               </Tilt>

            )
        })

        return(
            <StackGrid
              columnWidth="33.3%"
              gutterWidth={20}
              gutterHeight={20}
              duration={500}
              className="stackGrid"
            >
              {itemList}
            </StackGrid>
        )
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state)=>{
    return {
      items: state.items
    }
  }
const mapDispatchToProps= (dispatch)=>{

    return{
        addToCart: (id)=>{dispatch(addToCart(id))}
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Home)
```

Comment: You have a little problem there, you have an array of elements and you `.map` over then but uses `ref={(el) => { this.inputRange = el; }}`. This will override all values and only get the last one, you should have an array of `inputRange`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a race condition. It is because the `ref` isn't assigning `this.inputRange` soon enough before `componentDidMount`, so it is `undefined` when you try and add event listeners to the `input`.

You can try and add conditionals and various strategies, but that isn't the "React" way of doing this. It is no coincidence that the React way is also the most straightforward. Change those event listeners to be a synthetic event that React handles for you, by making it an inline `prop` inside the `input` element.

Take out the `ref` unless you need it for other things and add the event listeners inline.

```
<input
  onMouseDown={this.unlockStartHandler}
  onMouseStart={this.unlockStartHandler}
  // and so on
/>
```

React event listener prop names are always the normal JS name with `on` appended to the front (and retaining camelCase naming).

Comment: Thanks! If I remove the ref line and add the event listeners inline I still have the same error message. Do you know why?

Comment: Did you remove the contents in `componentDidMount` that are related to this change?

Comment: Yes, but now I got a new error ("TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of undefined") on line 70. My page is loading so far, but when I use the range input this error message is displayed. 
I updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Van_Gram/4vofz6jh/5/

Comment: @Chris I think I'm starting to pair program with you at this point ;). The issue you just described has nothing to do with your original question. I'm pretty sure it's because it's supposed to be `e.currentTarget.value`, not `e.target.value`.